# Styling overlapping annotations in text with HTML <SPAN> tags and CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, annotations, border, overlap

I want to annotate text with categories. Each categorie has a specific color. Also, I want to focus on the visualization of overlapping annotations.

### Annotations and Atoms

The part of the text (user selection), which is annotated, I call atoms.

For me there are 4 types of atoms which can overlap, described as follows:

1. Lorem { [ ipsum ] } dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. (Identity)
2. { Lorem [ ipsum ] dolor } sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. (Inclusion)
3. Lorem { ipsum dolor [ sit amet, } consetetur ] sadipscing elitr. (Overlap)
4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [ consetetur ] { sadipscing } elitr. (Neighbor)

We assume there are only 2 categories A with [ ] and B with { }. (but it works for more too)

All the tools I looked at overlap by background-color or different style types (like underlining A and background-color for B). When using background colors, the overlapping parts have usually a darker or a mixed color.

### CSS and SPANs

My approach is to **border** the atoms. So each atom gets wrapped in a `span` tag. I have some problems with the (3.) overlap. Of course, I broke it down to 4 `span`s: start, end and two for the overlapping part.

```
<span class="A outer start">iam nonumy</span>

<span class="A outer end overlap">
    <span class="B start">
    eirmod
    </span>
</span>

<span class="B end">tempor</span>`
```

1. The line-height needs to increase as more atoms are annotated and overlapping.
2. How do I join the spans with the same class A and B ? (I tried padding, but it is not working. Also I tried to decrease the `word-spacing`, but it works for the overlaps but breaks the normal text.)
3. How do I move `span`s using `z-index`, I know they have to be `inline-block` or `block` elements. If they are `block`, a `span` is spread over more than one line.

### Example

The example shows all 4 types. Also you can see the problem with the overlap and my attempt to use `word-spacing`, also in the last example, the purple atom should be at the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb62u/289/

Here is another example with `word-spacing`, I have to set it to -10 to join the parts.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb62u/297/

Answer (score 1):

- Use [percentage/length units](http://www.brunildo.org/test/vertical-align-length.html) or [images](http://www.brunildo.org/test/va_lineheight_m.html) with `vertical-align` to make `line-height` fluid
- Use relative/absolute positioning to [bookend](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/CSS_Menus) the spans

  ```
  position: relative; text-align:right; /* for the container, */
  position: absolute; left: 0; /* for the left aligned element, */
  display: inline; /* or */
  display: inline-block /* for the right element. */
  ```
- Use `white-space:nowrap` to avoid wrapping of text in `inline-block` or `block` elements

For example:

```css
#container{ position: relative; text-align:right; }
#lefty { position: absolute; left: 0; }
#lefty, #righty { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="lefty"><blockquote>left</blockquote></span>
  <span id="righty"><blockquote>right</blockquote></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Overlapping spans**

Negative `word spacing` makes the text unreadable, and it doesn't event connect those span parts if the e.g. `width` of the screen is changed in this example.
To overcome this, delete `word spacing` and put **negative margin** on the second span.

```
.marginNeg {
  margin-left: -10px
}

<div class="text">
  <span class="A outer start">kommt eine</span>
  <span class="B start marginNeg">
    <span class="A outer end overlap">neue</span>
  </span>
  <span class="B end">Zeile</span>
</div>
```