# Display:table + display: table-cell does vertical align but divs have nonsense widths

Tags: html, css

I have a code to create wrapper divs containing elements I want to be vertically centered.
Ok. This works fine for me, I can have a given height for top-parent container or a given height for one of the elements contained (img, span, etc). I have always a right vertically centered of elements (this is what I want)

But however I have this error.

The widths of divs have an arbitrary value, as if the browser distributed the space.
I cannot use 'float' because then the table-trick does not work.

The next example I have three divs and I have arbitrary widths....
I'd like the first and second divs aligned to the left, and the third to the right.
But I can't use float ,, this is the code ( the imgs are 'cut' , but you can see the pseudo-image)

```
<div style="display: table; width: 200px; background-color: #0099CC;">

  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..."=" width="32" height="82"></div>

  <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
  <span>Load file</span></div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..."=" width="32" height="32"></div>

</div>
```

Any idea would be really appreciated,

Comment: do you want the 3rd one to the extreme right of the page?

Comment: could you not give a width of 32 to your left and right div as this would allow your middle div to expand to the correct size.  Also what's the extra `="` at the end of your img src

Comment: >aneelkkhatri. I'd like to have some divs aligned to the left  & others to the right.   >pete : the extra = is simply an error,( even I think the broswer does nothing with it ) . And.... I dont want to have into acount the width of nothing... I'd like an automatic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Replace `display:table` with `display:inline-block`
- Use a container div with `position:relative`
- Use `text-align: justify` to spread out the elements equally
- Use a nested div with `position:absolute; right:0;` to realign the third element

Here are some related questions:

- [How to stretch a fixed number of horizontal navigation items evenly and fully across a specified container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/)
- [Styling overlapping annotations in text with HTML <SPAN> tags and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377964/styling-overlapping-annotations-in-text-with-html-span-tags-and-css/12202688#12202688)